# Formal smoothness of $A \to A[t]/(h)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, $T$ an indeterminate, $h=h(T) \in A[T]$, and $B:= A[T]/(h)$.

When $B$ is formally smooth over $A$? (If $h$ is monic, is $B$ formally smooth over $A$?).

Thank you very much.

**Edit:** In view of the comments, I further assume that $A$ is a domain (maybe a UFD) of zero characteristic, and $B$ is also a domain. 
Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217581/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything in sight is finitely presented like it is here, formally smooth is equivalent to the usual notion of smoothness. So it's enough to see whether such a map is smooth. There are obvious examples where this is not true- consider $A=\mathbb{F}_p$, $h=T^p$. Then by the Jacobian criteria, this variety is not smooth. For answering the question in general, the Jacobian criteria is probably your best bet, actually- take the formal derivative of $h$ and if it is zero simultaneously with $h$ anywhere, this is not smooth and therefore not formally smooth.

Comment: Thank you very much! (I have once asked a similar question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207595/when-a-smooth-algebra-is-regular, and truly knew that in my case formal smoothness is equivalent to smoothness). The Jacobian criterion is applicable for a given $h$; is it too difficult to obtain from the Jacobian criterion a general form of $h$ for which $A \to B$ is smooth? (I guess it is too difficult, maybe even impossible?)

Comment: I think you will have to just do the computation for each $h$ if you're pretty sure you want to let $A$ be any commutative ring- depending on the structure of $A$ (characteristic, is it a domain, etc) you might be able to get better conditions on $h$, but you won't be able to avoid doing some work with $h$ here.

Comment: Thanks! Please, can you elaborate a little/ refer me to books or papers about getting better conditions on $h$? For example, if $A$ is a domain (or a UFD) of zero characteristic, how should $h$ look like in order to get a smooth $A \to B$?

Comment: I am still curious about "depending on the structure of $A$ (characteristic, is it a domain, etc) you might be able to get better conditions on $h$", despite http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217581/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217620/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h-1-ldots-h-n?lq=1 (since maybe you thought about other results).

Comment: Jason Starr's comment is completely correct. What I meant is that sometimes generating the unit ideal is easier to check, ie if $A$ is a field and you can find all the roots of $h(t)$ and you know that none have multiplicity 2 or higher, you know that $(h(t),h'(t))=(1)$. There is no getting around the fact that you will have to do some get-your-hands-dirty work to answer your question. You need to check whether $(h(t),h'(t))=(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Interesting!